# about derivative of a matrix and trace

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have checked it up the following derivation of a formula:"

[image]

The question that I have is why the author uses the trace in the third part; supposedly it uses a formula derived from the properties of the trace that states that:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty lost as to what's going on here. Perhaps you could provide some more background, or a reference?

Comment: Taking the gradient with respect to $A^T$ is a felony in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

This is an awfully complicated way of deriving the derivative or gradient.

It is simpler to show that $\|J(\theta+h)-J(\theta) - (X \theta-y)^T X h\|$ is bounded above by $\|X^TX\| \|h\|^2$ from which we see that
 $DJ(\theta)(h) = (X \theta-y)^T X h = 
\langle X^T (X\theta -y), h \rangle$, where
$\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle $ is the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
It follows from this that
$\nabla_\theta J(\theta) = X^T (X\theta -y)$.

**Alternatively**:

We have $J(\theta) = (X \theta-y)^T (X \theta -y) = 
\operatorname{tr} ( (X \theta-y)^T (X \theta -y)  )$, since the quantity is 
a scalar.

Expanding the terms in brackets leads to a constant term, terms linear in $\theta$ and a term that is quadratic in $\theta$.

The derivative of the constant term is zero, the linear terms are straightforward, only the quadratic term needs some attention.

The quadratic term takes the general form $L(X)$, where we let $L(X)= \operatorname{tr} (X^T B X C)$, then
$L(X+H)-L(X) = \operatorname{tr}(X^T B H C+H^T B X C+H^T B H C)$. Since trace
is linear we have $\operatorname{tr}(H^T B H C) \le M \|H\|^2$ for some $M$, and so $DL(X)(H) = \operatorname{tr}(X^T B H C+H^T B X C) = \operatorname{tr}(CX^T B H +C^T X^T B^T H)$, where the latter uses
the properties $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$ and
$\operatorname{tr} (A) = \operatorname{tr} (A^T)$.

This gives $DL(X)(H) = \langle BXC+B^TXC^T, H \rangle$, from which we
have $\nabla_X L(X) = BXC+B^TXC^T$. This is using the inner product induced
by the Frobenius norm. If $X$  (and $H$, of course) is in $\mathbb{R}^n$, this
reduces to the usual inner product,
which gives the above result.

Comment: I am still lost why the author uses the trace on the third line

Comment: It is a long winded way of proving the result.

Comment: could you be so kind to give me an insight or formulae explaining why the trace appears there?

Comment: Note that if $s$ is a scalar, then $ s = \operatorname{tr} s$. Perhaps the author has derived the trace gradient earlier and would like to use it rather than the above expansion?

Comment: I'm not sure it helps, but I added some more detail above. In terms of the question, this is complete overkill, but the author may be leading up to something else, so I can't guess as to what her context was.